# Cannot get view or function to update on change of variable swift

Tags: swift, sorting, swiftui, view

I am trying to make this picker update what the list shows, I've tried a couple of solutions but I am relatively new to swift so I may not have implemented it correctly, here is the code to the page.

```
`import SwiftUI

struct SearchPage: View {

var categories = ["Name", "Price", "Health rating", "Kilojoules"]
//    var arrayOfProducts = TestProductList

// hacky solution to get minimal viable product, i know i should make the logic better but  i dont understand what i am doing wrong and this is my 5th attempt. if i have time i will fix
@State var NameArray: [MProduct] = TestProductList.sorted {$0.NameOfProduct < $1.NameOfProduct}
@State var pickedCategory = "Price"

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        // pick which category it sorts by, the category is picked category
        Picker("Sort", selection: $pickedCategory){
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) {
                Text($0)
            }
        }
        ViProductFile(productList: findcorrectsortedarray(Unsorted: NameArray, Category: pickedCategory)
        }
    }
}
}
```

`

Here is the code to findcorrectsortedarray

```
import Foundation

func findcorrectsortedarray(Unsorted: \[MProduct\], Category: String) -\> \[MProduct\] {
if Category == "Name" {
return Unsorted.sorted { $0.NameOfProduct \< $1.NameOfProduct }
} else if Category == "Price" {
return Unsorted.sorted { $0.Price \< $1.Price }
} else if Category == "Kilojoules" {
return Unsorted.sorted { $0.EnergyContent \< $1.EnergyContent }
}
else {
return 
}}
```

and the code for ViProductFile
import SwiftUI

`struct ViProductFile: View {

```
@State var productList: [MProduct] = []

var body: some View {
    List(productList)
    {
        ViProduct(product: $0)
    }
}

}
```

`

I have tried using onChange like this but it didn't seem to work

```
ViProductFile(productList: NameArray).onChange(of: pickedCategory){newValue in
NameArray = findcorrectsortedarray(Unsorted: NameArray, Category: pickedCategory)
```

as well as running the calculation as part of the variable (one of the solutions I found online)
I've also tried running it through to chatgpt and it gave me solutions which did not work.

It works the first time based on the pickedCategory but if I change the value of the picker it does not do anything.

Comment: Remove `@State` inside `ViProductFile`

Comment: thank you jnpdx but what did that do? it did fix the problem.

Comment: You should read about `@State`. Basically, it keeps a persistent and mutable state in a `View`. In this case, you're not mutating it inside that view -- you just want to display what is passed in. In your code, it was always showing the first value passed in.